# jQuery selector for ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used this library:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

and in order to use it I should use syntax like below:

```
autosize($('textarea#description'));
```

or any other javascript selector.
But my textarea loaded by ajax and it is not working.

Is there any other selector that works with ajax elements?
Thank you

Comment: How does your html look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the jquery selector around it and use `.find()` to narrow it down.

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function(responseHTML){
    // depending on what the function is doing you may need to append it to the body first.
    $(responseHTML).appendTo('body'); // or wherever you want to put it
    $textarea = $(responseHTML).find('#description');
    autosize($textarea);
});
```